# Time measurements differ on microcontroller

Tags: c, gcc, microcontroller, cpu-cycles

I am measuring the cycle count of different C functions which I try to make constant time in order to mitigate side channel attacks (crypto).

I am working with a microcontroller (aurix from infineon) which has an onboard cycle counter which gets incremented each clock tick and which I can read out.

Consider the following:

```
int result[32], cnt=0;
int secret[32];
/** some other code***/

reset_and_startCounter(); //resets cycles to 0 and starts the counter
int tmp = readCycles(); //read cycles before function call

function(secret) //I want to measure this function, should be constant time

result[cnt++] = readCycles() - tmp; //read out cycles and subtract to get correct result
```

When I measure the cycles like shown above, I will sometimes receive a different amount of cycles depending on the input given to the function. (~1-10 cycles difference, function itself takes about 3000 cycles).

I was now wondering if it not yet is perfectly constant time, and that the calculations depend on some input. I looked into the function and did the following:

```
void function(int* input){
    reset_and_startCounter(); 
    int tmp = readCycles(); 
   /*********************************
    ******calculations on input******
    *********************************/
    result[cnt++] = readCycles() - tmp;
}
```

and I received the same amount of cycles no matter what input is given.

I then also measured the time needed to call the function only, and to return from the function. Both measurements were the same no matter what input.

I was always using the gcc compiler flags -O3,-fomit-frame-pointer. -O3 because the runtime is critical and I need it to be fast. And also important, no other code has been running on the microcontroller (no OS etc.)

Does anyone have a possible explanation for this. I want to be secure, that my code is constant time, and those cycles are arbitrary...

And sorry for not providing a runnable code here, but I believe not many have an Aurix lying arround :O

Thank you

Comment: are there any conditionals in your code?  is the data aligned every time you feed it to your function.  does your code change alignment whenever you change the experiment.  can you insure there are no interrupts during the test?  have you examined the disassembly for each experiment with respect to the code under test?

Comment: variations are expected, microcontrollers are expected to be much more consistent that microprocessors not because of the processor but because of the system around them and how deterministic or not they are.  (but also the processor plays a role in how it fetches and caches and other factors).

Comment: the code does not contain conditionals. I did not cope with data alignment, I will have a look at alignment. The code itself does not change alignment. And no I have not yet looked at the assembly code. Interrupts disabled and no caches used.

Comment: but why would the code be constant time if  I measure it inside (+function call and return), while when measured from the outside, it seems not to be? Somehow this reminds me of the "Double-slit experiment". WELL: I changed the function to `always_inline` and it is const. time also when measured from the outside.... I don't get it

Comment: tmp should be volatile to avoid optimizations that mess with measurement of time.  and/or check the disassembly.

Comment: is it 1-10 cycles without changing the binary, consistently one value, then add/change code in that wrapper function and the count changes by a few?

Comment: it is very possible you are trying to get an accuracy that isnt possible.  we dont necessarily know the exact architecture of this design, how the busses work, how this count works with respect to when the processor samples it.  is it a pipelined processor.   the first place to start is always with the disassembly, if your time is consistent with a build but changes with what may or may not look like something unrelated, what does that disassembly show, code and data alignment can make a difference (how the fetching works is something we usually dont get to see).

Comment: you are relying on a function to get the cycles, what about wrapping the code under test with assembly language that specifically reads and stores the time if it really is a cpu register then that should be one or a few lines of code on either side of the code under test.  (yes the library call should be consistent one would hope but would have to see all of the code related to the library call)

Comment: is it worth worrying about a few counts out of a few thousand?  not enough info here to know if that is expected or not, being high level language code, and the list of possible cycle stealers, a few counts might be about right for accuracy.

Comment: Hard to be sure from the datasheet.  But that's a lot of horse power for a micro-controller and high clock rates.  Just run it several times so branch prediction choices play less of a role.

Comment: the function reading out the cycles is an builtin function which is one line of assembly. it reads one register of the core and thus should be accurate and non-interfering.. But thanks for your insight and tips

Comment: How do you change the value, do you recompile? If the code is in flash then alignment of the code can play a role, because there is usually some kind of prefetch ("flash accelerator").

Comment: Do you mean the secret? No, I am running a loop which changes the secret, but this is deterministic and I do not change this when i recompile. I do only move the measurement start/end points. And no flash is used, I am always working in the scratch pad RAM which has 1cycle access latency.

Answer (score 1):

The Infineon Aurix microcontroller you're using is designed for hard real-time applications. It has *intentionally* been designed to provide consistent runtime performance -- it lacks most of the features that can lead to inconsistent performance on more sophisticated CPUs, like cache memory or branch prediction.

While showing that your code has constant runtime on this part is a start, it is still possible for your code to have variable runtime when run on other CPUs. It is also possible that a device containing this CPU may leak information through other channels, particularly through power analysis. If making your application resistant to sidechannel analysis is critical, you may want to consider using a part designed for cryptographic applications. (The Aurix is not such a part.)

Comment: thank you, yes that is true there might be non const runtimes on different devices, but i specifically design the code for the aurix for a thesis. Timing side channels are the easiest one can exploit... That is why I need to make the code constant time. DPA etc. would be a further step which is not part of this thesis. Do you maybe have a clue why different measurement points lead to different outputs? one being const time, the other not?

Comment: Are your preconditions before calling your code always the same? Maybe the processor has to clean up some internal registers depending on the code executed before.

Comment: I am just moving the entry point and exit point of the measurement. nothing else...